# what is the equivalent of this java code to kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

what
 is the equivalent kotlin of the following java code:

```
F f=new F();
convert(f, HashMap.class);
```

This is what i have tried so far

```
val f = F()
convert(f, HashMap<*, *>::class.java)
```

This is the error i am getting:

Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just do this:

```
convert(form, HashMap::class.java)
```

Comment: Really helped me after 2 hours